# Как запустить HTML-код в Браузере (Firefox) из редактора Geany под Windows 7?

Tags: html, geany

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как запустить HTML-код в Браузере (Firefox) из редактора Geany под Windows 7? В интернете найти ответ не удалось. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2036369

Answer (score 0):

Используйте плагин WebHelper для Geany. Найти его можно тут: https://plugins.geany.org/webhelper.html

Comment: @РустамГимранов исправил ответ в соответствии с вашими рекомендациями. На будущее учту.

Answer (score 0):

установить команды сборки:
start firefox "%f"

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).